# Aggreagte Query on multiple columns : SQL Group BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate

I have a table having following columns

```
Item_no | Item_size | date | user_id | price | avg_price | no_of_items
```

I need following result:

I need all the items aggregated with given Item_size, need total price, average of avg_price and sum of no_of_items for given Item_size.

i.e
     Item_size, sum(price), avg(avg_price), sum(no_of_items) => All are aggregated on Item_size. So Item_size is primary key for this new table.

Comment: Have you tried to write a query for this?  If so, please edit the question and include it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use "GROUP BY" aggregate function

```
SELECT 
COUNT(item_no) as no_of_items,
SUM(price) as total_price,
AVG(price) as avg_item_price,
FROM table 
group by item_size;
```